# Highlight links in a Quick Links web part on SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint, modern-ui

We have added 4 "Quick Links" web/app part in one section on a SharePoint modern page. We would like to highlight links under "Quick Links web part 2" and "Quick Links web part 4" only. I have added React modern script editor. How do we archive the above requirement using CSS ? If it is not possible in CSS then we would like to introduce JS. I couldn't find a fixed tag name that I can grab and apply CSS except GUID.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to inject CSS by SPFX.
Check the demo shared by [hugoabernier](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss).
Main code:

```
export default class InjectCssApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<IInjectCssApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

    const cssUrl: string = this.properties.cssurl;
    if (cssUrl) {
        // inject the style sheet
        const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
        let customStyle: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
        customStyle.href = cssUrl;
        customStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
        customStyle.type = "text/css";
        head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", customStyle);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have Modern Script Editor webpart on the page. What CSS styles to add to highlight links in a particular Quick Links webpart. Note: I have multiple Quick Links webparts on the page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to add css to modern script editor,but it does nor work.

Comment: Thanks to Mikael Svenson. Check his modern script editor webpart on this link https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor  It works.